# How Can I Find Default User Directories in Elixir

Tags: elixir, cross-platform

In many programming languages, there is a library call (part of the base packages or an external module) to locate the user's home directory, the documents directory, the configuration directory, and so forth, that isn't platform-specific.  As an example of one that I've used recently for another language, Rust has "[dirs](https://lib.rs/crates/dirs)."  Is there an Elixir equivalent?

For example, I run a server on my local machine to handle some tasks, and recently wrote a client for it---a simple console application that sends a TCP request and gets a response---in Elixir.  I would like to pull the port number from the existing configuration file, if the file exists, so that the value isn't hard-coded.  I *could* do something like this, of course.

```
Path.join(System.user_home!(), ".config")
```

I guess `System.user_home()` is a start, itself, but not really sufficient.  It'll fail miserably on a Windows machine, for example.

Searching the web turned up examples in plenty of non-Elixir languages, ways to search the current directory for a file in Elixir, and how to get the most out of the `config` directory in a Phoenix project, but nothing that I could see for just getting the configuration (or a similar) directory.

So, assuming that this has been done before (and I have to assume it has been, given how established Elixir has become), what's the current method for retrieving the user's configuration folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully Elixir, but there is Erlang functions for that - [`filename:basedir/{2,3}`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/filename.html#basedir-2)

This function take the type of the directory as a first argument, which is one of the following atoms:

- `user_cache`
- `user_config`
- `user_data`
- `user_log`
- `site_config`
- `site_data`

And application name (also as atom) as a second argument.

Third argument may be a map containing:

- `os` - OS type used for the paths creation, there are 3 recognisable values - `windows`, `darwin` (macOS), and `linux` (which will use [XDG Base Directory Spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)). Any other value will be treated as `linux`. If not provided, then OS is automatically detected by `os:type/0` call.
- `author` - used only on Windows
- `version` - used only on Windows

Comment: That'll work; thanks!